# Using getElementsByClassName in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the code which I'm using but I'm getting this error that:

> object doesn't support this property or method

while using `getElementsByClassName`.
The new 2 variable I'm using is not getting filled please help me out, do let me know if I'm doing it the wrong way.

```
Sub PopulateTasks()
'Variable Declaration
Dim ie As Object
Dim noTaskText As String
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

url = "http://example/do/"
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate url
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 430
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 400
    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readystate = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With
Set link = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For i = 1 To 200
        For Each l In link
            If l.innertext = storyIds(i) Then
                l.Click
                Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readystate = 4
                    DoEvents
                Loop
                If InStr("No tasks have been defined.", ie.Document.Body.outerText) <> 0 Then
                    noTaskFound = True
                End If
                noTaskText = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("highlighted_message")(0).innerText

            If noTaskFound = True Then

            End If
        Next
            ie.Document.getElementbyId ("")                
            Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readystate = 4
                DoEvents
            Loop     
Next i    
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with "`new2`" but you are missing an "s" after "element" in `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: Two things I can think of: 1) the version of IE you are using does not support that method, and 2) after you `Click` the link elements, you need to *wait* for the page to load.

Comment: You don't `Set new2 = ...` to an `.innerText` property. Simply assign it to a string type var. `str = ie....innertext` (and declare your vars!)

Comment: in the html page there this entry <p class="highlighted_message">No tasks have been defined.</p>       I am trying to check if this text is present in the html page, if yes I am doing further work on that. I have tried including the missing s in getElementsByClassName() had done amistake while copying here also have waited for the page to load.

Comment: Are you now taking David's advice and waiting for the page to load after clicking the link? You *have* to do that. If Yes it would be useful to update your question with your current code.

Comment: Have added comments given by David and updated the code above, but in the InStr function too I am not getting the highlighted text value, not sure why, is that the reason I am getting this error?. but I have verified that the text is coming in source code of the HTML. Please advice.

Comment: You are using Instr incorrectly - should be `InStr(ie.Document.Body.outerText, "No tasks have been defined.")`  As florentbr notes below though, if you can't provide a reachable URL then it's difficult to provide any useful help.

Comment: Thanks Tim, had made that InStr mistake in haste, its workingfine now and regarding the link, I am afraid the link wont open at your end.

Answer (score 3):

To get an element with the class name, I would use querySelector:

```
Set element = ie.Document.querySelector(".classname")
Debug.Print element.innerHTML
```

With your example:

```
txt = ie.Document.querySelector(".highlighted_message").innerText
If txt = "No tasks have been defined." Then
    noTaskFound = True
    Exit For
End If
```

Comment: Its giving me the same error while I am using querySelector :(

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message? I'm pretty sure you're getting another one, at least with querySelector.

Comment: Its "Run time error 438:" object does not support this property or method. same as what it was giving for ClassName method