# Is there a piece of code which will pull an address out from a Google Search

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to get the address of a company when you search for [Company name] + "Address" on google. I can get the "About 20,500 results (0.49 seconds)" no issue because the div id is always resultStats however, for the address its a HTML Class that is called: Z0LcW. Not sure if it changes.

I am trying to confirm that the trading addresses provided by a potential supplier are valid. Its for 4k addresses and i dont want to have to manually verify it.

The idea came from: [Using VBA in Excel to Google Search a keyword and return indexed pages on google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26617110/using-vba-in-excel-to-google-search-a-keyword-and-return-indexed-pages-on-google)

I have looked at these guys who were very helpful conceptually:
[Using getElementsByClassName in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974796/using-getelementsbyclassname-in-excel-vba)

```
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html, ObjResultdiv As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 1 To lastRow

    url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText

    'Debug.Print XMLHTTP.ResponseText


If html.getElementsBytagname("Z0LcW") Is Nothing Then
    str_text = "0 Results"
Else
    str_text = html.getElementsBytagname("Z0LcW")
End If
    Cells(i, 2) = str_text
    DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
```

The answer should be: 31B, Avenue One, Station Ln, Witney OX28 4XZ

https://www.google.co.uk/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNQ6p6lh1ZFfS6dGwsDcg45wKgmICw%3A1569864526381&ei=TjuSXaPnFvHC8gL81a2gCg&q=beadlight+ltd+address&oq=beadlight+ltd+address&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1272.2467..2622...0.0..0.85.635.8......0....1..gws-wiz.......0j0i22i30j33i160j33i21.NErA1FvTnr8&ved=0ahUKEwijxsKLifnkAhVxoVwKHfxqC6QQ4dUDCAs&uact=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library so we can `Dim` a `HTMLDocument` and use the methods available there.

"Z0LcW" is a class so I used getElementsByClassName("Z0LcW") to return the results instead of getElementsByTagName.

Once we actually get the result we can use the `.innerText` property of the element to get the text value.  I'm not a whiz at classes and tags, so be aware there may be duplicates at some point so you might need to loop through a collection of elements later on.

```
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, ObjResultdiv As Object
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim html As New HTMLDocument

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

start_time = Time
Debug.Print "start_time:" & start_time

For i = 1 To lastRow

    Url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" & Cells(i, 1) & "&rnd=" & WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 10000)

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", Url, False
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    XMLHTTP.send

    'Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile") 'Don't need this as we early bind an HTMLDocument with the methods we need
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText

    'Debug.Print XMLHTTP.ResponseText


If html.getElementsByClassName("Z0LcW") Is Nothing Then
    str_text = "0 Results"
Else
    str_text = html.getElementsByClassName("Z0LcW")
End If

Debug.Print str_text.innerText 'innerText is the property that will give the text inside the elements found

    Cells(i, 2) = str_text.innerText
    DoEvents
Next

end_time = Time
Debug.Print "end_time:" & end_time

Debug.Print "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
MsgBox "done" & "Time taken : " & DateDiff("n", start_time, end_time)
```

Comment: Thank you so much mike. Thats been a great help. Im just going to add a handler for when no address is found.